# Android in-app billing testing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I created product id list for my application in android developer account. Also i created test account to test my in-app purchase implementation. My concern is do i get charged on entering card details from test account for buying the product, to test in-app billing implementation. What is the best way to test in-app billing?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test an in- App is to

```
mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", "");
```

This way you neither have to upload your app nor you have to create in app products on marketplace.

Comment: that sounds great! How would I do that with In-App Billing v3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the one mentioned by ingsaurabh, however in case you want to do a real testing of in-app billing I would recommend going through the entire grind.

Things to test:
a. Purchase
b. Cancel
c. Refund 
d. Restore transactions

For all these you would need a real purchase, which would get charged to your account. However later on you can go ahead and cancel it from your developer console and it would get refunded.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do end to end testing is to do a real purchase. You have to set up a test account on the developer site first. You don;t have to worry about the charges. You can always refund it.